# Rust: Shorten generic type bounds

Tags: generics, rust

Is there a way to shorten generic type bounds in rust?
This is the mess I have to put on a lot of structs impls etc.:

```rust
pub struct IncomingClientMessageWithAddress<State, Msg>
    where State: AppState + Clone + serde::Serialize + serde::de::DeserializeOwned + std::marker::Unpin + 'static,
          Msg: AppEvent + Clone + serde::Serialize + serde::de::DeserializeOwned + std::marker::Unpin + 'static {
...
```

I am basically looking to do something like this (I know that below doesn't work for traits):

```rust
type MyStateAlias = AppState + Clone + serde::Serialize + serde::de::DeserializeOwned + std::marker::Unpin + 'static;
type MyEventAlias = AppEvent + Clone + serde::Serialize + serde::de::DeserializeOwned + std::marker::Unpin + 'static;


pub struct IncomingClientMessageWithAddress<State, Msg>
    where State: MyStateAlias,
          Msg: MyEventAlias {
...
```

Comment: For starters, you can import those traits so you don't have to use them fully-qualified each time.

Comment: There is an RFC for "trait aliases", which would let you define a name for a collection of constraints. https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1733-trait-alias.md. It isn't yet stabilised, but you can use it in nightly: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=03e9dbd770eb927b98a798b08b1f959d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I sometimes realized that all occurrences of a certain trait are associated with other traits. In your case, if `AppState` *always* occurs with `Clone` and `Serialize`, you could already require these on top of state:

```
trait AppState : Clone + Serialize {/*...*/}
```

If not, you could still define an auxiliary trait

```
trait AuxAppState: AppState + Clone + Serialize {/*...*/}
```

and require `State : AuxAppState`.

Then, to automatically derive `AuxAppState` you'd have to `impl` it for every type that also `impl`ements `State`, `Clone` and `Serialize`:

```
impl<T> AuxAppState for T where T: AppState + Clone + Serialize {}
```

Finally, defining and `impl`ementing the `AuxAppState` could possibly be done by a [macro to save some keystrokes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9944e61b9052799be0ec7432517ab827):

```
macro_rules! auxiliary_trait{
    ($traitname: ident, $($t:tt)*) => {
        trait $traitname : $($t)* {}
        impl<T> $traitname for T where T: $($t)* {}
    }
}
```

All of this can possibly be done one day with [trait aliases](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1733-trait-alias.md).

Moreover, I started to require trait bounds only where they are actually needed. E.g. in many cases, the `struct`-definition itself does not rely on the trait bounds, only the `impl`, so I started omitting them on the `struct`, only keeping them in the `impl`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use new traits with blanket implementations for this:

```
use serde::Serialize;
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;
use std::marker::Unpin;

pub trait AppState {}
pub trait AppEvent {}

pub trait StateTrait : AppState + Clone + Serialize + DeserializeOwned + Unpin + 'static {}
impl<T : AppState + Clone + Serialize + DeserializeOwned + Unpin + 'static> StateTrait for T {}
pub trait EventTrait : AppEvent + Clone + Serialize + DeserializeOwned + Unpin + 'static {}
impl<T : AppEvent + Clone + Serialize + DeserializeOwned + Unpin + 'static> EventTrait for T {}

pub struct IncomingClientMessageWithAddress<State, Msg>
    where State: StateTrait, Msg: EventTrait
{
    ... 
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c99d616c37f7f2f64583104ccf41f988)